# How to make the current worker stop its execution and go to the next job?

Tags: laravel

On a job, I have a worker that executes a Python script (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html). The Python script takes either less than 2 seconds or 20 seconds (it's a request to a WHOIS server).

I put the "job" timeout to 2 seconds. I expected the worker to stop there and skip to the next job. However, I still have the same issue.

Before, the worker attempted the job, the script failed after 20 seconds, it put the job as "failed" and it went to the next job.

Now, the worker attempts the job, the scripts takes more than 2 seconds, it puts the job as "failed", it waits another 18 seconds and goes to the next job.

So, my problem isn't really solved. It just puts the job as "failed" more early.

Is there a way to force the worker to stop the execution and go to the next job?

Comment: Does it wait 18 seconds because the job is stuck? How are you checking this with laravel horizon? Redis? Also you can always sync jobs or multi-thread or assign them to different workers. Kindly provide more details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example well... a little code would help